# Ticket selling probability puzzle

Tags: puzzle

I was talking with a friend of mine about a simple statistical puzzle that we weren't able to solve due to our ignorance about the statistics world.

Consider a ticket selling web. A musical event is coming up, and there are only 400 tickets available for a total of 800 solicitants. Since the web is not optimized at all for heavy internet traffic, there is a high chance of if getting freezed and unusable. In order to lighten this internet traffic, there is the possibility of getting multiple tickets with a single purchase.

There is a group of 10 friends wanting to attend this event. When purchasing all the tickets at once, I understand there would be a probability of 50% of getting them in the first attempt (being 10 tickets it should be even less, but for the sake of simplicity let's keep it at 50%).

One of the friends, in an inspirational moment, talks about splitting the group in two groups of 5 members, so that the probability of getting all the tickets would increase substantially.

**Is this idea correct?**

My *very basic* understanding of statistics makes me think that even if the probability of getting tickets for at least one group would increase substantially, there would be a sligthly lower probability of getting all the 10 tickets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If tickets are booked by splitting in two separate groups (Say Group A and Group B) of 5, there are 4 possible cases

1. Group A gets 5 tickets, Group B books 5 tickets
2. Group A gets 5 tickets, Group B books 0 tickets
3. Group A gets 0 tickets, Group B books 5 tickets
4. Group A gets 0 tickets, Group B books 0 tickets

Assuming that both ticket booking events are independent with each having probability of 0.5, following are the probabilities for each case

[image]

**Conclusion :**

- Probability that you will be able to book 5 or more tickets is increased to 0.75  i.e.  P(Case 1) + P(Case 2) + P(Case 3) , so if you are OK with 5 or more tickets, splitting in two groups is better strategy.
- If you want 10 tickets or nothing , then single group is better strategy as splitting in 2 groups will reduce the probability of getting 10 tickets to 0.25 (Case 1) as compared to 0.5 in single group.